# Error running a Heroku Python + Selenium & Chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, heroku

I'm trying to make a web scraper using python. On my win10 system this works fine.
But when I deploy to Heroku I get the following error. I don't know why it's not working.

Code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

URL = "https://www.google.com"  #URL

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), options=options)
driver.get(URL)
```

Error :

```
2022-06-05T13:47:06.222744+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/main.py:12: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
2022-06-05T13:47:06.222759+00:00 app[worker.1]:   driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ['CHROMEDRIVER_PATH'], options=options)
2022-06-05T13:47:06.815862+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-06-05T13:47:06.815885+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/main.py", line 12, in <module>
2022-06-05T13:47:06.816238+00:00 app[worker.1]:     driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ['CHROMEDRIVER_PATH'], options=options)
2022-06-05T13:47:06.816242+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
2022-06-05T13:47:06.816407+00:00 app[worker.1]:     super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
2022-06-05T13:47:06.816422+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
2022-06-05T13:47:06.816570+00:00 app[worker.1]:     RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
2022-06-05T13:47:06.816594+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 275, in __init__
2022-06-05T13:47:06.816794+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
2022-06-05T13:47:06.816809+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 365, in start_session
2022-06-05T13:47:06.817076+00:00 app[worker.1]:     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
2022-06-05T13:47:06.817091+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
2022-06-05T13:47:06.817333+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
2022-06-05T13:47:06.817348+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
2022-06-05T13:47:06.817529+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
2022-06-05T13:47:06.817616+00:00 app[worker.1]: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
2022-06-05T13:47:06.817616+00:00 app[worker.1]:   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
2022-06-05T13:47:06.817617+00:00 app[worker.1]:   (The process started from chrome location /app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Hope anyone is able to help.

Version :

- Python v3.9.13
- Selenium v4.2.0
- Heroku 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Solution***

With `selenium4` as the key `executable_path` is deprecated you have to use an instance of the `Service()` class along with `ChromeDriverManager().install()` command, like below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: `[WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======
[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 102.0.5005
[WDM] - Get LATEST chromedriver version for 102.0.5005 google-chrome
[WDM] - There is no [linux64] chromedriver for browser 102.0.5005 in cache
[WDM] - About to download new driver from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/102.0.5005.61/chromedriver_linux64.zip
[WDM] - Driver has been saved in cache [/app/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/102.0.5005.61]` I got another error

Comment: is your problem that you mentioned in question is solved by provided solution ?